# Trouble in integration test finding resource

Tags: grails

I'm using Grails 1.3.6.  I have this code in my service ...

```
            if (folder) {
                    path = "json/${folder}/${page}.json"
            } else {
                    path = "json/${page}.json"
            } // if
            def file = ApplicationHolder.application.parentContext.getResource(path).getFile();
```

Normally the file is correctly retrieved from the web-app/json directory, but when I run an integration test (through grails test-app), the above code fails when trying to retrieve the resource ("java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [json/index.json] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist").  Below is my integration test.  How do I tell it where to find the resource?

Thanks, - Dave

```
class HomeControllerTests extends GroovyTestCase {
...

void testGetAllJSON() {
            def controller = new HomeController()

            // Call action without any parameters
            controller.index()

            def responseStr = controller.response.contentAsString

            assertTrue( isValidJSON(responseStr) )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That may be because the context path is different for the tests versus web-app.  Try instead using the [resource tag](http://www.grails.org/Tag+-+resource):

```
if (folder) {
    path = "${resource(dir:'json',file:"${folder}/${page}.json")}"
} else {
    path = "${resource(dir:'json',file:"${page}.json")}"
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks but that doesn't work.  Fails with the same FileNotFoundException as before